# How to reset or reload the powerbi embed report in Angular

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded, power-bi-angular

I am currently using 'powerbi-client-angular' new package which is introduced by Microsoft team. As part of implementation I want to reload or reset my report which is loaded already. Please help me how to reset or reload the report in powerbi-client-angular.

Answer (score 0):

1. To reload the embedded report, use:

```js
await report.reload();
```

This method reloads the embedded report and resets the current filters and user interactions, returning the embed back to its original state.

2. To reset the embedded report, use:

```js
const embedContainer = $('#embedContainer')[0];
powerbi.reset(embedContainer);
```

Here the `embedContainer` is used to get a reference to the embedded report HTML element.

Please find the reference:
https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Developer/Replace-replace-current-embedded-report-with-new-one-on-same/m-p/161556

Comment: In the new package powerbi-client-angular we don't have container. I am not finding how to reset the report with this new package.

Answer (score 0):

I found something that is not perfect but it works for me (refresh the same report with different parameters)

It seems to need to clear all filters then set a new access token and finally refresh the dataset.

```
ResetEmbed(token: string): void {
    this.reportObj.getReport().reload();
    this.reportObj.getReport().setAccessToken(token);
    this.reportObj.getReport().refresh();
  }
```